# While{ while{code}} not working wright

Tags: php, mysql

I have noticed that if i have a while{ while{}} loop, not all the data in a MYSQL database is shown...

here is the PHP (this is a working code...)

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","xfiddlec_user","public");
mysql_select_db("xfiddlec_max");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
?>

<script>
 $(function() 
 {
    var icons = 
    {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $( "#dam" ).accordion({
        icons: icons,
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true
    });
 });
</script>
<?php
        $construct ="SELECT * FROM Noutati";

        $constructaug ="SELECT * from Noutati WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) = 8 AND YEAR(DataIntroducere) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
        $run = mysql_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());
        $runaug = mysql_query($constructaug) or die(mysql_error());
        $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
        $foundnumaug = mysql_num_rows($runaug);

    if ($foundnum==0)
    {
        echo "Nu avem noutăți!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<div id='dam'>";


        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug) )
        {

            echo"
            <h3>August 2013</h3>
            <div><br>";
                while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug))
                {
                    $Luna = $runrows ['Luna'];
                    $Ziua = $runrows ['Ziua'];
                    $Mesaj = $runrows ['Mesaj'];
                    echo "
                    <table class='noutatitabel'>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='faramargini'>
                                <div class='data'>
                                    <div class='luna'>$Luna</div>
                                    <div class='ziua'>$Ziua</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class='albastru'>$Mesaj
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>";                      
                }
            echo"
            <br><hr><br></div>";
        }


        echo"</div>";
    }

?>
```

The database contains 6 rows.

When the above code is executed, an accordion menu appears but only 2 rows of that database are shown (for the specific month - the 1-st row is not shown) and i just don't understand where is the problem. If i remove the first while loop, the query shows 3 rows. I also have a fiddle for this and can be found [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j45-r4g).

Have I done something wrong? Have you ever encountered this? How can i solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why have you nested 2 identical whiles?! All this is do is discard the first record row...

Comment: Remove the first while loop, no logic in that

Comment: i can not remove the first loop because then it will display the h3 tag and i want it to be displayed only if there are results...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @ionvoinescu I understand now. Please check my answer. I have addressed this for you

Comment: As an aside, you'll find your HTML easier to work with if you separate out your business logic from your presentation. Don't put large chunks of HTML into echo statements, as your IDE no longer can understand the structure of your document (or validate it, or syntax colour it). Keep PHP as much as possible, either in a big block at the start, or in tiny one-statement clauses. The rest is HTML, and it becomes _so_ much easier to debug. Ping me if you are interested in an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And why exactly do you have these two loops? They're both going through the same mysql result resource, so they're interfering with each other.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($runaug) > 0 )
    {

        echo"
        <h3>August 2013</h3>
        <div><br>";
            while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug))
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the pointer from `mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug)` to run nested loops. because once the child loop finish iterating the parent loop will have gone past the end of the result as well. If you really just want to run two loops use

```
mysql_data_seek($rs,$offset);
```

you will have to keep a reference to the offset of the parent loop when you enter the child loop and then reset the pointer accordingly.

Comment: actually you can. use `reset($runaug);` that resetting the pointer at the array.

Comment: @JohnnyJS wouldn't that cause an infinite loop then?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use just one *while*:

```
else 
{
    echo"<div id='dam'>";

    if($foundnumaug)
      echo"<h3>August 2013</h3><div><br>";

      while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug) )
      {
          $Luna = $runrows ['Luna'];
          $Ziua = $runrows ['Ziua'];
          $Mesaj = $runrows ['Mesaj'];
          echo "
          <table class='noutatitabel'>
            <tr>
              <td class='faramargini'>
                <div class='data'>
                  <div class='luna'>$Luna</div>
                  <div class='ziua'>$Ziua</div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class='albastru'>$Mesaj
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table><br>";            
      }

      echo"<br><hr><br></div>";
    }

    echo"</div>";
}
```

The reason of your problem is that the first *while* fetches first row and moves the internal data pointer **to the next row**, than the second *while* fetches all remaining rows.

Comment: the first while checks if there are rows to be displayed and if so then displays the h3 tag...

Comment: But you already have `if ($foundnum==0)` to check if there are rows. Just copy/paste my code and you will see that it works.

Comment: well... that checks if there are rows in general. if there aren't  then displays the "nu avem noutati!" message... else... the code above is part of a much bigger code.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Than you have to replace the first while with `if($foundnumaug)`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the improved mysql extension, [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

After that, I'm sure that you don't want to exact same loops, so revise them, most likely you are losing data there.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly from the comments, the first WHILE is used to check if there are any results.

Then you need to change the first WHILE:

```
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runaug) )
```

INTO

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($runaug) > 0 )
```

Otherwise the first WHILE will consume your first row. So you will never show the first row.